# How to initialize and use Custom / Support classes in MVC 6 with Asp.Net Core 2.0

Tags: class, asp.net-core-mvc, helper

```
public sealed class SessionContext
{
    private ISession httpContext;
    public  SessionContext(ISession httpContext)
    { 
        this.httpContext = httpContext;
    } 
    public string UserType
    {
        get
        {
            return httpContext.GetString("_UserType");
        }
        set
        {
            httpContext.SetString("_UserType", value);
        }
    }
    ...... More properties ..... 
 }

public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private AppSettings _appSettings; 
    private SessionContext session = null;
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;
    private ISession httpContext => _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session;   
//I don't like this constructor as it is getting initialize or every controller call.
    public HomeController(IOptions<AppSettings> myAppSettings, IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        _appSettings = myAppSettings.Value;
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
        appSettings = new AppSettings(_appSettings);  //Should initialize only once.
        session = new SessionContext(httpContext);  
    }
}
```

I have questions regarding ...

1. How to initialize  and use Custom / Support classes in MVC 6 with Asp.Net Core 2.0
   When I Initialize these classes, they getting initialize or every controller call. That is very redundant.
2. my SessionContext class is getting re-initialize every time. So I am loosing the values when I call this class from another controller.

   I tried this approach but, not much of use.
   services.AddSingleton();

Comment: Finally ... resolved the problem. Thanks to the blog Strongly Typed Configuration Settings in ASP.NET Core Part II   .... Written by Khalid Abuhakmeh

Answer (score 0):

Move from question to answer:

> ```
> public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
> {
>    services.AddOptions();
>    services.AddSingleton<SessionContext, SessionContext>(); 
> //calling the extension class to instantiate the classes which we require earlier.
>    services.AddMyProjectHelper(Configuration)  
> }
> ```
>
> Created a extension class... where it initializes the support classes
>
> ```
> public static class MyProjectHelperExtensions
>   {
>         public static IServiceCollection AddMyProjectHelper(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
>         {
>             var section = configuration.GetSection("AppSettings");
>
>            // we first need to create an instance
>             var settings = new AppSettings();
>
>            // then we set the properties 
>             new ConfigureFromConfigurationOptions<AppSettings>(section).Configure(settings); 
>
>            var session = services.BuildServiceProvider().GetService<SessionContext>(); 
>
>            // then we register the instance into the services collection
>             services.AddSingleton<MyProjectHelper>(new MyProjectHelper(settings, session));
>
>            return services;
>         }
> }
> ```
>
> finally controller ctor uses the DI for the required class. Now I have avoided redundant initialization of support classes.
>
> ```
> public SecurityController(MyProjectHelper objHelper, SessionContext sessionContext)
> { 
>    session = sessionContext;
>    projectHelper  = projectHelper  ?? objHelper; 
> }
> ```
>
> Now, I am able to share the session variables which I have set in my support classes
>
> ```
> private SessionContext session = null;
> public HomeController(SessionContext sessionContext)
> {
>    session = sessionContext;
> }
>
> [Authorize]
> public IActionResult Index()
> {
>    if (session.CurrEmployee != null)
>    {
>       ViewBag.Name = (session.CurrEmployee.FirstName + " " + session.CurrEmployee.LastName);
>       return View();
>    }
> }
> ```